# Wildcard Subdomains to pass subdomain value to a script

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard

I have a project im working on, when a user tries to accesses x.website.com it would show results for a specific state, how would I go about this without making 52 subdomains manually?

Is there a way to do it with htaccess? but this should also work if, state.website.com/search.php is accessed, it would show all the results for state X so I need it to be a constant variable.

Or is there a better way? Could anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a [wildcard DNS record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS) as `*.example.com`.  Any subdomain accessed which doesn't have a real DNS record defined will be sent to the wildcard record.

Check with your domain registrar to see if you are permitted to create a wildcard record.

In your .htaccess file, you can map the subdomains like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
# The state is captured as %1
RewriteRule . /index.php?state=%1 [L,QSA]

# More generically - pass the state to any request
# I think this will work without going to a redirect loop
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1?state=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Inside `index.php` once you have retrieved the state from the querystring, you can store it in `$_SESSION` and use that as a search filter.

Comment: so would I have to have both of them done? DNS wild card and htaccess?  Also am I wrong in thinking that this wouldnt work for lets say state.website.com/search.php ? as it would try to pass to index.php?

Comment: You will need both the wildcard DNS record and .htaccess. However, you can just store the querystring value of `?state=` in `$_SESSION` with PHP and retrieve it for searches.